# How to mock an object's function which writes to the same object in python?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest

```
class Employee:
    address = models.ForeignKey(Address)

    def setZipCode(self, zipcode):
       setattr(self, 'zipCode', zipcode)

    def set_address_property(self, target_property, value):
        try:
            setattr(self.address, target_property, value)
            self.address.save()
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            # TODO. Figure out what to do here
            print 'Cannot save'
            return
     def get_address_property(self, target_property, default):
        try:
              return getattr(self.address, target_property)
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
             return default

@property
def zipCode(self):
    return self.get_address_property('zipCode', None)

@zipCode.setter
def zipCode(self, value):
    self.set_address_property('zipCode', value)

def functionToTest(employee):
    # Blah Blah Blah...
    employee.setZipCode(123)

def testFunctionToTest(self):
    employee = MagicMock()
    employee.address.zipCode = None
    employee.attribute.setZipCode = lambda x, y: setattr(x.address, 'zipCode', y)
    functionToTest(employee)
    self.assertEquals(employee.address.zipCode, 123)
```

If I try to run this test, I still get `employee.address.zipCode` as `None` instead of 123. How can  I fix this issue?

Comment: What is the point of `setZipCode` at all? If you must have a method, why are you using `setattr` rather than just assigning the value to `self.address.zipCode`?

Comment: Let me edit the setZipCode function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to test if the attribute is actually set; your test should only cover if the method is called at all:

```
employee = MagicMock(spec= Employee)
functionToTest(employee)
employee.assert_called_once_with(123)
```

Testing if `employee.setZipCode()` works correctly is the subject of unit testing the `Employee` class, and is outside the scope for testing the `fuctionToTest()` function.

Comment: It makes sense. But i want to verify this property is also set correctly or not.

Comment: @user1159517: again, that's testing if `Employee` is correctly implemented. You are not testing `Employee` here, you are testing `functionToTest`. That function *doesn't need to care* if `Employee` is correctly implemented or not. It just needs to trust that it is.